# Timestamp is rendered inconsistently on Heroku dyno

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, datetime, heroku

I am having a rough time getting a Rails 5 view (hosted on a Heroku dyno) to render a consistent timestamp value. The Heroku support team can't figure out the issue.

1) I visit the specific view (an order form) and observe a datetime value rendering is incorrect. The time code should be `2000-01-01 01:06:10` but instead reads `1999-12-31 19:06:10`.

This is what is fully rendered below in the html.erb view (sourced from a datetime column in Postgres):

`1999-12-31 19:06:10 -0600`

The code used to render this timestamp is simple: `item.time_start` which is from a Model named `Item` with an attribute/column named `time_start`. No other formatting is going on with this process.

2) I then click on the `Restart All Dynos` link on the Heroku Dashboard

3) I immediately visit the same page and observe the time code as correct:

`2000-01-01 01:06:10 UTC`

Does anyone have ideas why this change would occur randomly during each day? Why does a server restart change the timestamp presentation?

### Schema

```
create_table "order_items", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.time  "time_start"
  t.time  "time_end"
end
```

### Stack/Config

```
Ruby 2.4.1
Rails 5.0.2
Postgres 9.6.2
production.rb setting: config.time_zone = "UTC"
```

Comment: version of PG driver? version of ActiveRecord?

Comment: also you're storing non-UTC values in PG but you expect the view to be in what timezone exactly?  I'm not sure I'm clear what raw data is in PG vs. what Rails displays...

Comment: Version of Active Record is 5.0.2 (like the Rails version specified above), if I access the datetimestamp in PG, it comes back as `01:06:10`

This is stored on PG as a `time` field

I have everything set to UTC. That's all I expect.

Comment: Does it possibly display correctly if your migration is `t.datetime`?

Comment: No idea. This problem never happens on local nor our staging (Heroku) server. This is unique to our Heroku production app.